# How to point a Json array to a local image?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm new at this so sorry if this is basic but I'm trying to use an array in a json file and have it point to an image in my asset library but I'm running into problems.  Its written as:
[
  {
  "image":"shrew",
  },
]

Is it wrong to write it as a string?  Do I need to have specific code to translate the string into my image names?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Edit:

The error I'm getting is on line 
    TrackPic.image = image

"Use of unresolved identifier 'TrackPic'"

```
class QuizModel: NSObject {

func getQuestions() -> [Question] {

    // Array of question objects
    var questions:[Question] = [Question]()

    // Get Json array of dictionaries
    let jsonObjects:[NSDictionary] = self.getLocalJsonFile()

    // Loop through each dictionary and assign values to our question objs
    var index:Int
    for index = 0; index < jsonObjects.count; index++ {

        // Current JSON dict
        let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = jsonObjects[index]

        // Create a question obj
        var q:Question = Question()

        let imageName = jsonDictionary["image"] as! String
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        TrackPic.image = image


        // Assign the values of each key value pair to the question object
        q.image = jsonDictionary["image"] as! String
        q.questionText = jsonDictionary["question"] as! String
        q.answers = jsonDictionary["answers"] as! [String]
        q.correctAnswerIndex = jsonDictionary["correctIndex"] as! Int
        q.module = jsonDictionary["module"] as! Int
        q.lesson = jsonDictionary["lesson"] as! Int
        q.feedback = jsonDictionary["feedback"] as! String


        // Add the question to the question array
        questions.append(q)
    }

    // Return list of question objects
    return questions
}
```

Comment: There is no requirements, just make sure you unwrap your string.

Comment: You should give us more details. What type of problems are you having?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Could not cast value of type '_NSCFString' to 'UIImageView'.  I wish I could give better details but I don't know what details to give.  The error comes up on my line that reads q.image=jsonDictionary["image"] as! UIImageView   Please help thanks!  How do I unwrap the string?  With a '?' somewhere?

Comment: you should always include a code sample which illustrates your problem in your question.
If you want to add a code sample, just edit your question instead of writing it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

you first need to get the image name from the json like you did

```
let imageName = jsonDictionary["image"] as! String
```

(If you want to be certain that you are parsing your JSON correctly, be sure to write the imageName to the console)

Then you need to initialise a `UIImage` with `UIImage(named: String)` with you image name from json so

```
let image = UIImage(named : imageName)
```

Then you have your image, and you can put this on an `UIImageView`.

I suppose in your case, this would be

```
q.image = image
```

IF `q` is a `UIImageView`

Comment: I edited my question and added the code after trying to implement your suggestions but I obviously didn't do it right.  Would you mind taking another look?  I'm hoping to call more than one image as the user goes through a series of questions.  Thank you!

Comment: You haven't defined `TrackPic` anywhere. You should delete the line `Trackpic.image = image` and change the line `q.image = ... As! String` to `q.image = image`